# How to store a List with own data type in an object array list

Tags: java, arrays, list, object, casting

I have an List listObject and i want to store a List pointListForObject  for every object of listObject.
How can i make it work?

```
class Points {
    private int start;
    private int stop;

    public Points() {
        start = 0;
        stop = 0;
    }

    setter and getter... 
 }

 List<Object[]> listObject = new ArrayList<Object[]>;
 List<Points> pointListForObject = new ArrayList<Points>;
    ...
    Points point= new Point();
    point.setStart(1);
    point.setStop(2);

    pointListForObject.add(point);
    listObject.get(0)[1] = pointListForObject;
```

And now i want to get the points in another method back, but i don't know how to cast or convert in the right way.
My idea is:

```
List<Points> usePointsOfObject = (List<Points>) listObject.get(0)[1];
```

And here I get an:
Exception in thread `"main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to java.util.List`

I tried different possibilities(to cast or convert) that i know but it doesn't work
I have no ideas..

Comment: I did not understand listObject.get(0)[1] = pointListForObject; listObject is a list which contains Object[] and pointListForObject is a list. This is where JVM is throwing the exception.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. I want to store the list "pointListForObjects"(here are a lot of points in it) as an element in the "object array listObject.get(0)[1]". Is it possible? Because to store an "int variable" or "string variable" in listObject.get(0)[1] is possible, so how can i store and restore a list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After

pointListForObject.add(point);

you should have
Object[] objArr=list.toArray(new Object[pointListForObject.size()]);

then
listObject.add(objArr);

Comment: After

pointListForObject.add(point);

you should have Object[] objArr=pointListForObject.toArray(new Object[pointListForObject.size()]);
=> I agree.
then listObject.add(objArr);

Comment: you want to add the object array to the list (listObject). thats why I wrote it. if you wanted something else, please do let me know

Comment: After

pointListForObject.add(point);

you should have Object[] objArr=pointListForObject.toArray(new Object[pointListForObject.size()]);
=> I agree.                                                                                                             
then listObject.add(objArr); => i don't agree, I need the right position of the list and of the object's element, that's why I use listObject.get(0)[1]=objArr;   But now my question is, how could i restore the list from the object?  Makes it sense: List<Points> use = (List<Points>)listObject.get(0)[1];

Comment: List<Points> use = (List<Points>)listObject.get(0)[1]; is incorrect, it would throw compilation error, because listObject is a list of objects and you are typecast it to (List<Points>). Assuming you are trying to get the first element from the array, you should use - List<Points> use = (List<Points>)((Object[])listObject.get(0))[1];

Comment: I get the same exception as before... =(

Comment: Have you changed your source code; if yes, please share

Answer (score 0):

Now i solved my problem

```
class Points {
    private int start;
    private int stop;

    public Points() {
        start = 0;
        stop = 0;
    }

    setter and getter... 
 }

 List<Object[]> listObject = new ArrayList<Object[]>;
 List<Points> pointListForObject = new ArrayList<Points>;
    ...
    Points point= new Point();
    point.setStart(1);
    point.setStop(2);
```

To store a list in an object of arrays

```
 pointListForObject.add(point);
            Object ob = pointListForObject;
            listObject.get(0)[1] = ob;
```

To restore a list from an object of arrays and to use it as a list

```
Object ob = (Object) listObject.get(0)[1];
List<Points> list = (List<Points>) ob;
```

Thanks for helping and sharing your knownledge and time!

Comment: Every generic object like String, Integer, boolean, List or in this example Point can be stored in an Object. When restoring it you have to cast it to the original "object" like point or List<Point>...